# Jquery image slider with moving images

Tags: jquery

I want to make an image slider that looks as if you 
move inside the image. 
an example (done with flash) to understand what i'm talking about: 
http://www.wi-unternehmensgruppe.de/denkmalschutz/berlin/lesley-lofts.html

the idea is a slider that would change the image focus so it would look more dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this plugin 
http://jquery.kidsil.net/slidenswap/

Should do sort of what you want.